# Redirect on another html page

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to NodeJS and express, and here is what I want to do :

After checking the connexion values, I want to redirect my user on his main page. I don't want to change the URL, but just show another html page.

Here is the code, and where I want to put the redirection :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server = server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

 socket.on('connexion_client', function(data) {
  if(input_are_ok) {
  // When the client is connected & his input are checked

  // HERE: I want to redirect to 'public/index.html'

  }
 }); // socket.on
}); // io.on
```

Thanks.

Comment: If my memory is correct, `res.redirect(path)` does what you want. Check out the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect)

Comment: Yes, I saw there is the redirect possibility, but I don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `res.redirect([status,] path)` like this:

```
if (input_are_ok) {
    res.redirect('public/index.html');
}
```

This will redirect to the given URL using the specified HTTP status code status. If no status code is specified, the status code defaults to 302 (which is fine in most use cases). More information in the [official documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect).

Comment: But what does res refers to ? I know I have to call the app by one of his methods, but I don't know which in my case.

Comment: Ah yes now I see the problem, I was thinking you were inside an Express middleware `function(req, res, next)`. Since you're using `socket.io` for communication, I think it's probably easier to send a message back to the client that says "logged in". The client will then do a redirect (`window.location`) to the `public/index.html` page.

Comment: In my case res.redirect('/login') merely sends the login.html content in the response of the ajax call made. How do I actually open up login page. It happens very easily in java MVC frameworks. How do we do that in node.js